# Python: instantiate an object to a reference

Tags: python

What I am asking might not be possible in Python and probably stems from my being used to pointers, but this is how it goes: is the following achievable in python?

```
class A(object):
    #body of class

a = A() #create a new object
b = A(a) #"b" is now an alias for "a"
```

My naive attempt to do this was

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, A):
             self = x
```

But, of course, this is non-sense since self is just a local variable.

EDIT: To be clear, this is not about simple variable assignment (i.e. `b=a` creates an alias but I don't care). This question came while I was trying to construct a loop with lots of objects of the same type:

```
class A(object):
    #blah

l = []
for cond in conditions:
    tmp = A(*cond)
    l.append(tmp)
```

If `cond[0]` is another object of type A, then `tmp` is just a reference to that object.
Now, there is a work-around for everything, but that's not what I am asking. I'd like to know if there is a solution to my original question.

Comment: What's wrong with `b = a`?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a quick guide to [how Python variables work](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: This is trivial in python: `b = a`. Pretty much, if you are used to C, you can think of all python variables as `Py_Object` pointers.

Comment: @StefanPochmann, `b=a` is not possible because of what I am trying to do. I would like to be able to create a bunch of objects dependent on certain conditions. I want to initialize them all the same way, hence the question.

Comment: .... **what exactly do you mean**?

Comment: @Ivan You may want to look at `__new__` function instead of `__init__`. What you are trying to achieve is possible.

Comment: @freakish yeah, you could intercept object creation, to just return that argument instead of initializing again... might require a meta-class

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I want to loop over obj_i = A(*args) and if args[0] is another object of type A, then I want obj_i to become a reference.

Comment: @freakish, could you post a solution?

Comment: @Ivan can you edit your question and elaborate a bit more? Even if it is more pseudo-codish. There may be a simple solution that doesn't require a meta-class. Note, the point freakish is making is that by the time you reach `__init__` it is too late, you need to intercept object creation in the *constructor*, which is `__new__`, not `__init__`

Comment: Why are you calling `A` at all? If you want `b` to refer to the same object as `a`, why are you not simply doing `b = a` instead of `b = A(a)`?

Comment: @Ivan: How do you expect `b = A(a)` and `b = a` to differ? If you want `a` and `b` to be initialized the same way, why not just make a function that creates an instance of your class? `factory = lambda: A(1, 2, 3)`. Then, `a = factory()` and `b = factory()` would do what you want. Or are you trying to make a shallow clone of `a`? Without more information, your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with `__new__`:

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, param=None):
        if isinstance(param, A):
            return param
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, param=None):  # should match __new__ signature
        if isinstance(param, A):
            return
        self.param = param
        # normal initialization
```

that being said you probably want to rethink your architecture.

Comment: While this is a solution to the original question, this logic really should be inside of the `for` loop, not in `A.__new__`. `A`'s constructor shouldn't make accommodations for `conditions` being a heterogenous container.

Comment: Thanks, this was a principle question. Is `__init__` called from `super().__new__` only?

Comment: @Ivan the default `__new__` implementation (the one you call via `super()`) calls `__init__`. You can call it manually if you wish.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get this to work in python 3.5, I get `TypeError: object() takes no parameters`.

Comment: @freakish, this calls the `__init__` method regardless of what I pass to `A(...)`. According to the documentation, `__init__` is always called as long as `__new__` returns same class type as the object being created. Thus, could you add an additional `if isinstance(param, A): return` to the `__init__` method for completeness and I'll select this as the correct answer (as it is).

Comment: @Ivan true. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

IF you want to do this it has to happen in the objects [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) method.  That's where you can affect the creation of new objects, as opposed to [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) which modifies them after their creation.  One way to do this would be

```
class A:
    def __new__(cls, copy=None):
        if copy: # This assumes that instances of A cannot be falsy
            if isinstance(copy, A):
                return copy
            else:
                raise ValueError("Argument not of type A")
        else:
            return super().__new__(cls)

a = A()
b = A(a)
b is a # True
```

Comment: What do I need to add in case I also want to pass arguments for regular initialization?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is actually to use a meta-class here, especially if you plan on using inheritance, although, meta-classes do add some complexity to that situation. If only, I would appeal to the fact that this is the common approach to creating a singleton class, which is very similar to what you are doing in principle. But here is a sketch:

```
In [43]: class MyMeta(type):
    ...:     def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    ...:         if isinstance(args[0], cls):
    ...:             return args[0]
    ...:         else:
    ...:             return super(MyMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    ...:

In [44]: class A(metaclass=MyMeta):
    ...:     def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
    ...:         print("initialized")
    ...:

In [45]: a1 = A(1, 1)
initialized

In [46]: a2 = A(2, 2)
initialized

In [47]: a3 = A(a1, 3)

In [48]: [hex(id(x)) for x in (a1, a2, a3)]
Out[48]: ['0x103ccd160', '0x103ccd198', '0x103ccd160']

In [49]: a1 is a2, a1 is a3
Out[49]: (False, True)
```

Note, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

> `__new__()` is intended mainly to allow subclasses of immutable types
>   (like `int`, `str`, or `tuple`) to customize instance creation. It is
>   also commonly overridden in custom metaclasses in order to customize
>   class creation.

Also, note that using this approach, `__init__` isn't called again, which *may* be what you want.

```
In [53]: class A(object):
    ...:     def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    ...:         if isinstance(args[0], A):
    ...:             return args[0]
    ...:         return super().__new__(cls)
    ...:
    ...:     def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):  # should match __new__ signature
    ...:         print("initialized")
    ...:

In [54]: a1 = A(1, 1)
initialized

In [55]: a2 = A(2, 2)
initialized

In [56]: a3 = A(a1, 3)
initialized

In [57]: a1 is a2, a1 is a3
Out[57]: (False, True)
```